# why can not set Android SDK location for visual studio 2017 xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

First , when i update visual studio 2017 and the Android SDK location setting been clear , i don't know why ?

So I navigate to the Android SDK location in File Explorer, copy the path and 
paste it into the Android SDK Location box  and save it, the visual studio 2017 always show error message , i can't save it .

[image]

Comment: the SDK needs to be at that location first.

Comment: I am sure there is.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem when updating to VS 2017 15.5.2 where my Android SDK installation appeared to be corrupt. Symptoms were:

- The green run button just said "Start" instead of showing a list of simulators. (I'd checked I had the Android project set as StartUp Project.)
- All of the buttons in the Android toolbar in VS were disabled, so I couldn't e.g. open the Android SDK Manager
- Going to the SDK location and attempting to run 'SDK Manager.exe' failed as it could not find a "tools" folder
- Opening the Android project's properties in VS and selecting the "Android Manifest" tab would produce a "This property is not valid when the SDK is not installed" error

I've no idea if you are having the same issue, but I fixed it by reinstalling 
VS's Mobile Development workload as follows:

1. Run the Visual Studio Installer through the Start menu
2. Click 'Modify' on your installation
3. Uncheck 'Mobile development with .NET' and click 'Modify' again
4. Once it has finished, repeat steps 2 and 3, this time *checking* the 'Mobile Development with .NET' module

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Copy this path into your 
`Options > Xamarin C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`